# Magento 2: Set Item weight programmatically

Tags: magento2.3.3

I'm going to set the weight of the product when adding to the cart.

```
<event name="sales_quote_add_item">
   <observer name="product_sales_quote_add_item" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\ProductWeightObserver" />
</event>
```

By this, I'm able to set weight but when placing an order it's overridden by some core logic of Magento.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ProductWeightObserver implements ObserverInterface
{


/**
 * @param EventObserver $observer
 * @return void
 */
public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
{
    $item      = $observer->getQuoteItem();
    $product   = $item->getProduct();
    $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);        
    $item->setWeight(2.0); // to set item weight        
    return $this;
}
}
```

Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

**=> events.xml :**

event name="sales_quote_add_item"
**Changed to** 

event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after"

**=> Observer :**

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
    $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
    $item->setWeight(2.0);
    $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try the below code in your observer:**

```
$item->getProduct()->setWeight('2.0');
```

Answer (score 0):

update your code you need to save product and if below code still not work then load product by id

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ProductWeightObserver implements ObserverInterface
{


/**
 * @param EventObserver $observer
 * @return void
 */
public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
{
    $item      = $observer->getQuoteItem();
    $product   = $item->getProduct();
    $product->setWeight(2.0);
    $product->save();
    return $this;
}
}
```